# Run a Batch on Windows Startup with Elevated Privilege from a Guest User

Tags: windows-7, windows, administrator, uac

My brother and sisters usually access to my computer (Windows 10) by a normal user account so that they cannot harm the system by accident. I was wondering if it's possible to set a program from my admin account to run on windows startup with elevated privilege (a game for example that requires admin rights).

I've discovered regedit paths like the following where you can set programs to run on startup but they do not get admin rights:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon"

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce"

"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run"
```

Is there a way to achieve so? Maybe by a configuration as library's computers have.

Comment: "they do not get admin rights": did you try with that registry settings? First try, then answer. I run a firewall (as admin) with the 3rd one.

Comment: no, this is not possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grant admin rights on an application](https://superuser.com/questions/512921/grant-admin-rights-on-an-application)

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator I'm using windows 10, does it work for this windows version?

Comment: @Bita the tool proposed by the accepted answer works on Windows 10 accusing to their website.